# Are SQL Server CLR and T-SQL stored procedures identical to the caller?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, clrstoredprocedure

To write some dummy stored-procedures I was wondering if I could just write them in C# since I don't know T-SQL very well.

Are C# and T-SQL versions of the same procedure indistinguishable to calling code e.g. C++/C#/Java code using standard database library classes?

Comment: My personal opinion is that while C#/CLR procedures have their place, you're pounding a square peg into a round hole by using them for everything in your app. Proceed with caution!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the caller won't know the difference. However, there are a few API differences:

- Parameters of LOB types (i.e. `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, `VARBINARY(MAX)`, and `XML`) cannot have default values in SQLCLR objects. (Microsoft Connect suggestion to vote for, perhaps: [Support default parameter values for NVARCHAR(MAX), VARBINARY(MAX), and XML types in SQLCLR objects](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1565637/support-default-parameter-values-for-nvarchar-max-varbinary-max-and-xml-types-in-sqlclr-objects) )
- You cannot pass in TVPs to SQLCLR objects.
- You cannot return the following datatypes from SQLCLR objects:

  - `SMALLDATETIME`
  - `SMALLMONEY`
- You cannot pass in or return the following datatypes to / from SQLCLR objects:

  - `CHAR`
  - `VARCHAR`
  - `TEXT`
  - `NTEXT`
  - `IMAGE`

Outside of that technical answer to the Question, there are some things to consider:

- What specifically do you feel is easier to do in C# than in T-SQL?
- What exactly is being considered "dummy"? Are you just needing a signature? If so, it would be far easier to do that in plain T-SQL. All it takes for T-SQL to do a mock stored procedure is:

  ```sql
  CREATE PROCEDURE SchemaName.ProcedureName
  (
    @Param1name  Param1Type,
    @Param2name  Param2Type,
    ...
  )
  AS
  SELECT  CONVERT(resultField1type, NULL) AS [resultField1name],
          CONVERT(resultField2type, NULL) AS [resultField2name],
          ...
              ;
  ```
- The term "dummy" implies that these will be replaced with something else later. What will they be replaced with? T-SQL Stored Procedures? Who will write those if you don't know T-SQL?
- If you don't know T-SQL, and you don't have anyone helping you that does know T-SQL (hence needing to make the "dummy" stored procedures in SQLCLR), then how do you know that you are structuring this solution correctly? You could be going in the completely wrong direction, regardless of T-SQL vs SQLCLR.

Comment: @TT. Yes, sorry.  I have updated to be clearer about that, and with a link to my suggestion to support defaults on those types :-)

Comment: In response to your good questions, an external supplier is providing procedures with an agreed declaration. I just want to write some local versions I can test my ODBC code against. And I figured it would be interesting ;)

Comment: @Mr.Boy If you have agreed-upon signatures, then it is much easier to do this in T-SQL. I updated my answer with an example. Even if you don't know much T-SQL, I can't see any benefit in trying to do this via SQLCLR, especially if you are not well versed in SQL Server and how certain things in .NET don't work as one who is used to Console / Windows / Web apps would expect. For more details on what I am referring to, please see this article that I wrote: [Stairway to SQLCLR Level 5: Development (Using .NET within SQL Server)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/119429/)